# Padding a time on the left with sprintf?

Tags: php, printf

I'm trying to pad a time (playtime of an MP3) using sprintf() in PHP.

```
sprintf("%02d:2d:2d", $time);
```

The function that returns the time gets, for example, '1:56' if the MP3 is 1 minute 56 seconds long, and that call brings back "01:56:00" (whereas it needs to be 00:01:56).  How can I make this work?  How can I tell sprintf to pad on the left?

Or is there a better way to go about this?  A more appropriate function maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'll need to calculate each element separately, so how about:

```
sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", floor($time/3600), floor($time/60)%60, $time%60);
```

Comment: Thanks, mine ended up a little different, but you put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [date-function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Something like this should work, if $time is in unix timestamp format:

```
print(date("H:i:s", $time));
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use [strftime($format,$timestamp)](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) ... probably as this:

```
strftime("%H:%M:%S",$time)
```

greetz

back2dos